# In Python, how do I increment a command?

Tags: python, opencv

Does anyone know the easiest way to increment the below block of code with a loop? (This is OpenCV,  but I guess the concept is applicable to Python in general.)

```
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.jpg')
img3 = cv2.imread('img3.jpg')
img4 = cv2.imread('img4.jpg')
```

and so on...

I've unsuccessfully tried various loops eg,

```
for num in range(0,n):
    prog = 'img {} = cv2.imread('img{}.jpg')'
    exec (prog)
```

Comment: I formatted your question.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) explaining how to format posts on SO.

Comment: Create a for loop (e.g `for i in range(1, n):`) and then in that loop create a `filename` string as `filename = 'img + str(i) + '.jpg')` followed by `img = cv2.imread(filename)`. You can then append each `img` to a list. Also the `os` packages supports looping through a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
list_img = []

for i in range(10): #Read 10 images
    list_img.append(cv2.imread("img{}.jpg".format(i)))
```

---

To show the image, or access it use the following code:

```
my_awesome_image = list_img[0]

cv2.imshow("My image!", my_awesome_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would this not just append the list, whereas I want to execute the imread command, which this doesn't seem to do?

Comment: It will read the image and store it inside `list_img` :)

Comment: The only problem is when I go to use eg img1 later on in my program I get NameError: name 'img1' is not defined...

Comment: You can't access the image by typing `img1` but by accessing it from the list, such as `list_img[0]`

Comment: I see! Thank you very much for clarifying :) Done!

Comment: Thanks to everyone else as well, helping this beginner along :)

Comment: That's what this site is for! Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Jakub's reply, you could use python's handy f-strings: `list_img.append(cv2.imread(f"img{i}.jpg")`, which does the same thing, but i a bit more readable imo

Comment: Wow I didn't even know that's a think! +1 from me.

Comment: once starting to use them, you can never go back ;)

Comment: note: they were introduced in something like python 3.6, so when working with older versions, you might run into trouble

Answer (score 0):

As other users suggested you can iterate over a list of filenames.

Suppose that your files are placed in a specific folder, then you can automatically load all the files in that folder matching a particular template with their name:

```py
import os
import re

FILENAME_REGEX = re.compile(r'image\d+\.jpg')  # template to match filename: image1.jpg, image2.jpg

img_folder = 'path to the folder'
images = [cv2.imread(os.path.join(img_folder, curr_file))
          for curr_file in next(os.walk(img_folder))[2] if FILENAME_REGEX.match(curr_file) is not None]
```